# Working with Katta ( Lucene, Hadoop )

Tags: lucene, hadoop, katta

Can any one provide me with some sample Java code as how to go about storing the Lucene index in a HDFS( Hadoop File Sytem ), using Katta.

Answer (score 2):

Katta is wrapper for Lucene indexes. A folder containing several lucene indexes form a katta index. I had worked on this long back and dont have code handy.

You have to install katta in each nodes along with Hadoop. It wouldnt be that difficult if you try. One of my colleague has written a [article on lucene indexing and searching using hadoop](http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/226300241;jsessionid=XSMBECWKKPFFFQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN?pgno=1). It may help you.

Comment: Harsha, sorry to disturb you. I followed your colleague's tutorial, but i have a hard time to get the command executes correctly on hadoop. Are you availalbe to take a look? Or can your colleague adds some hadoop command line execution example for his code? Thanks!